# Accessing vector at index 0 when it's empty

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

Why I can still get the value from `vectors[0]` even I already `pop_back()` at the first step?
I'm guessing now my `vectors` is empty and check it by calling `empty()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Vector2 {
    int x, y;

    Vector2(int _x, int _y)
        : x(_x)
        , y(_y) {}

    Vector2(const Vector2& vec)
        : x(vec.x)
        , y(vec.y) {
        std::cout << "[Copy] Vector2{" << x << "," << y << "} copied!"
                  << std::endl;
    }

    void Print() {
        std::cout << "[Print] Vector2{" << x << "," << y << "}" << std::endl;
    }
};

void PrintVectors(const std::vector<Vector2>& vectors) {
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    for (auto& vector : vectors) {
        std::cout << "Vector2{" << vector.x << "," << vector.y << "}"
                  << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Vector2> vectors;
    vectors.push_back({21, 78});

    PrintVectors(vectors);

    // First
    vectors.pop_back();
    if (vectors.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Empty condition!" << std::endl;
    }
    vectors[0].Print(); // ---> I thought I'd get an error at this point.
    vectors.insert(vectors.begin(), {vectors[0].x + 1, vectors[0].y});
    PrintVectors(vectors);

    // Second
    vectors.pop_back();
    vectors[0].Print();
    vectors.insert(vectors.begin(), {vectors[0].x + 1, vectors[0].y});
    PrintVectors(vectors);

    // Third + no pop_back needed
    vectors[0].Print();
    vectors.insert(vectors.begin(), {vectors[0].x + 1, vectors[0].y});
    PrintVectors(vectors);

    // 4th
    vectors.pop_back();
    vectors[0].Print();
    vectors.insert(vectors.begin(), {vectors[0].x + 1, vectors[0].y});
    PrintVectors(vectors);
}
```

Then, this condition let me debugging through **gdb**. I see the value of `_M_` is changing, but I have no clue what's going on (I can't see the pattern or relation between `_M_start` and `_M_finish`).

Comment: Try `.at(0)` instead of `[0]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessing an empty vector at index 0 with `operator[]` is out of bounds and thus [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and doing it renders your entire program invalid. The compiler is allowed to generate whatever result it wants. *Any* behaviour is acceptable. 
You cannot reason about programs containing UB.